# How to add a DropDownList from the codebehind in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

So I'm currently creating a DropDownList.
This is my Code from the codebehind file in the Page_Load method.
 I've got a Content tag in the aspx file and the DropdownList should be inside this Content tag. Currently, there no panel or
DropDownList displayed.**Is there anything missing?**
 So in the end it should add the DDL directly from the codebehind file, without writing something inside the aspx file.(+There would be code for the datasource but I can't show it)

```
  public Panel GetDropDownList()
{
    // Create drop down list and data source
    Panel pnlChannel = new Panel();
    DropDownList ddlChannel = new DropDownList();
    ListItem limDefault = new ListItem();
    SqlDataSource sdsChannel = new SqlDataSource();

    // Configure data source


    // Configure drop down list
    ddlChannel.DataTextField = "Channel";
    ddlChannel.DataValueField = "Channel";
    ddlChannel.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    ddlChannel.DataSourceID = "sdsChannel";



    // Configure default list item
    limDefault.Selected = true;
    limDefault.Text = "All";
    limDefault.Value = "-1";

    // Add controls to static panel in footer
    ddlChannel.Items.Add(limDefault);
    pnlChannel.Controls.Add(ddlChannel);
    pnlChannel.Controls.Add(sdsChannel);
    return pnlChannel;
}
```

Comment: You have to add your panel directly into your .aspx page where you will load the dropdownlist as a control

Comment: But I've got a masterpage, and I don't want to add it there, because I will only need it on one page.

Comment: Then add it to your child page instead of your masterpage

Comment: So theres only the masterpage and then every single page gets generated